# Canvas Javascript: gridDraw(ctx) function not working not generating errors on Chrome

Tags: javascript, canvas, functional-programming, html5-canvas, frontend

Please help figure out why this is not working. The drawTest function (shown for proof of concept) works but not the drawGrid function. What am I doing wrong?

```js
'use strict';
window.onload = init;
function init() {
    let can = document.getElementById('canvas');
    let ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    drawTest(ctx);
    drawGrid(ctx);
}

function drawTest(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 0, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)';
    ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 50);
}

function drawGrid(ctx, elSize = 10, width = .3, color = 'green') {
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.stroke.style = color;
    var lineX = ctx.width/elSize - 1;
    var lineY = ctx.height/elSize - 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= lineX; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(elSize * i, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(elSize * i, ctx.height);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    for (var i = 1; i <= lineY; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, elSize * i);
        ctx.lineTo(ctx.width, elSize * i);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context has no width, so ctx.width and ctx.height are undefined. instead, use ctx.canvas.width and ctx.canvas.height.

```
function drawGrid(ctx, elSize = 10, width = .3, color = 'green') {
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.stroke.style = color;
    var lineX = ctx.canvas.width/elSize - 1;
    var lineY = ctx.canvas.height/elSize - 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= lineX; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(elSize * i, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(elSize * i, ctx.canvas.height);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    for (var i = 1; i <= lineY; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, elSize * i);
        ctx.lineTo(ctx.canvas.width, elSize * i);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/d8x2v98o/2/)

Comment: Thank you.it worked! But how should I properly go about attaching the length and width into the ctx object using javascript OOP? For example should I create a function that returns an object with the properties set? Can you show me in a canvas example?

Comment: The canvas width and height properties are the standard properties describing the pixels in the canvas, so it's perfectly acceptable to access these width and height properties as in the example. Note that the canvas *style* width and height properties may make the canvas visually appear larger or smaller than the canvas.width/canvas.height properties. Differences between the style and the canvas properties will create a visualization that appears stretched or condensed.